# Spring boot JmsTemplate Junit test with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I'm struggling to get createMessage method to recognize by unit test.  I'm not sure if my approach is correct.  I'm a newbie with Mockito.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my class

```
@Component
public class MyMessageSender {

    @Autowired private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String queueName, String message) {
        jmsTemplate.send(queueName, new MessageCreator() {
        
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyMessageSenderTest {

    @InjectMocks MyMessageSender myMessageSender;

    @Mock JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Test 
    public void testSend() throws JMSException {
        jmsTemplate.send(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(MessageCreator.class));
        myMessageSender.sendMessage("test", "test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateMessage() throws Exception {
        Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
        TextMessage textMessage = Mockito.mock(TextMessage.class);
    
        textMessage.setText("hello");
        String RESPONSE_TEXT = "hello";
    
        // it raised java.lang.NullPointerException here
        assertEquals(session.createTextMessage(RESPONSE_TEXT).getText(), textMessage.getText());
    }
}
```

So I added

```
Mockito.when(session.createTextMessage(RESPONSE_TEXT).thenReturn(message); 
 assertTrue((session.createTextMessage(RESPONSE_TEXT).getText().toString().length() > 1);
```

It works but based on jacoco code coverage, it doesn't show it's covered this line `return session.createTextMessage(message);`
Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You need to **mock** the behaviour of the mocked `TextMessage` instead of calling the setter: `when(textMessage.getText()).thenReturn(RESPONSE_TEXT);`. Same goes for the behaviour of the mocked `Session`-objects. Mocking is about defining behaviour that is independent from the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.